# Out of class constructor definition for a specialized class template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to define a constructor for an explicitly specialized class template outside the class definition, as so:

```
template <typename T>
struct x;

template <>
struct x<int> {
    inline x();

    /* This would have compiled:
    x() {
    }
    */
};

template <>    // Error
x<int>::x() {
}
```

But it seems to be an error. Comeau says: `error: "x<int>::x()" is not an entity that can be explicitly specialized`, even though the complete class is what being specialized.

What's the issue here?

Comment: I've never seen this before. It would be interesting to know the answer here. Generally though, I keep my templates inline coded to reduce all the unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Using g++, I get the error `template-id ‘x<>’ for ‘x<int>::x()’ does not match any template declaration`.  However, if I change it so it's not a constructor, I still get an equivalent error: `template-id ‘pants<>’ for ‘void x<int>::pants()’ does not match any template declaration`.

Comment: @Josh D: Sure it will do. In fact, it's the only option for, say, a `char_traits<>`-style class that doesn't have a meaningful generic definition - class parameters for which specializations are undefined will generate a compilation error.

Comment: @Steve M. I was misinformed. Thanks for correcting me. The offending lies have been removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't specify `template<>` for the definition:

```
template <typename T>
struct x;

template <>
struct x<int> {
  x();
};

inline x<int>::x(){}
```

Edit: The constructor definition isn't a specialization, so `template<>` is unnecessary. It's the definition of the constructor of a specialization. So, you just need to specify the type like for any other non-template class.

Comment: Didn't think to drop the template declaration. Thanks.